# Can a Blood Hunter / Bard use Blood Curse of the Eyeless and Cutting Words on the same attack roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, blood-hunter

I've seen a reactionary curse that says you roll your hemocraft die to reduce an attack roll that you can see. Since this and the Lore Bard's use of Bardic Inspiration work mechanically the same via Cutting Words and uses a resource, could/should it be used in the same reaction to reduce a roll?

> When a creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll, you can use your reaction to roll one hemocraft die and subtract the number rolled from the creature’s attack roll. You can choose to use this feature after the creature’s roll, but before the DM determines whether the attack roll succeeds. The creature is immune if it is immune to blindness.
>
> Amplify. You apply this curse to all of the creature’s attack rolls until the end of the turn. You roll a new hemocraft die for each affected attack.

From DnD beyond

Comment: Have you got the text for reactionary curse? I assume that uses a reaction?

Comment: Can you please let us know which source you're using for the Blood Hunter?

Comment: Are you asking about a blood hunter/bard multiclass using both Cutting Words and reactionary curse against a single roll or are you asking about a bard and a blood hunter working together to apply both to a single attack roll?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Bard's Cutting Words

> When a creature that you can see within 60 feet of you makes an attack roll, an ability check, or a damage roll, you can **use your reaction** to expend one of your uses of Bardic Inspiration, rolling a Bardic Inspiration die and subtracting the number rolled from the creature’s roll.

PHB, emphasis mine

#### Blood Hunter's Blood Curse of the Eyeless

> When a creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll, you can **use your reaction** to roll one hemocraft die and subtract the number rolled from the creature’s attack roll.

Blood Hunter by Matt Mercer, emphasis mine

Since both features require the use of your reaction, you have to choose one of them. If you can somehow take multiple reactions in a single round, combining magical effects would allow you to use both since they are different effects. As [Peter Cordes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/15436/peter-cordes) pointed out in the comments, even Matt's Cobalt Soul Monk subclass which can have multiple reactions would have to choose one effect for the trigger.

Comment: Great first answer!

Comment: Even if you multi-class 11 levels into Matt Mercer's Cobalt Soul Monk subclass to get multiple reactions per turn, you can still only spend 1 reaction per trigger.  (https://twitter.com/matthewmercer/status/1105321543788199936 has a dropbox link)